# The AMP module requires the PHP AMP library

Tags: 8

I installed Drupal 8 and amptheme. I downloaded the AMP module and the library files. When I tried to install the module, I got the following message:

> The AMP module requires the PHP AMP library.

The library files are in libraries/amp-library. I think the library location is incorrect.

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 3):

This module requires the use of Composer to install its libraries. You can learn more about Drupal and Composer on drupal.org's documentation hand book [Installing modules' Composer dependencies in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/composer-dependencies). The AMP module project page also has a brief description of how to install on Drupal 8.0.5.

Comment: Thank you, I have installed Composer Manager module, but when i run username@locahost:/var/www/SITENAME$ composer drupal-update shows warning like **Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.**